# How to forward file content to StringSink with Crypto++?

Tags: crypto++

I'm using some test code for Crypto++ just to get used to it.
There's a function:

```
void DecryptFile(const char *in, const char *out, const char *passPhrase)
{
    FileSource f(in, true, new DefaultDecryptorWithMAC(passPhrase, new FileSink(out)));
}
```

where `DecryptFile` is `#define DecryptFile DecryptFileW` (I'm on Windows).

So, file deciphering is called via `DecryptFile(name_f.c_str(), "decrypted_alphabet.txt", cpass);`
If `cpass` is correct, then the contents of `name_f.c_str()` file is written to `decrypted_alphabet.txt`.

**Now the problem**: I can't find the way to forward file contents to `StringSink` rather than to a file! I tried manually calling this:

```
string out;
FileSource (in, true, new DefaultDecryptorWithMAC(cpass, new StringSink(out)));
```

but this returns some crappy characters like `ъ!$` or `5(#` (every time new). Maybe I can't explain my problem properly, so, here's piece of code, where I try to crack a 4-digit protected txt file: http://pastebin.com/FJng91Y6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to forward file content to StringSink with Crypto++?
>   ...
>   Now the problem: I can't find the way to forward file contents to
>   StringSink rather than to a file! I tried manually calling this:
>
> ```
> string out;
> FileSource (in, true, new DefaultDecryptorWithMAC(cpass, new StringSink(out)));
> ```

This is working as expected.

---

> but this returns some crappy characters like ъ!$ or 5(# (every time new). Maybe I can't explain my problem properly, so, here's piece of code, where I try to crack a 4-digit protected txt file

Yes, that sounds about right (if I am reading it correctly). You are generating collisions on the 4-digit passcode. To avoid the collisions, you need a longer passphrase.

---

Maybe you should finish enumerating the combinations rather than stopping the processing on the first match:

```
if (strlen(cpass) > 0){
    printf("Alphabet password is: %s\n", cpass);
    return;
}
```

Collect all the potential decryption, and then further analyze them looking for a "good" decryption. Maybe you should save them to a file using the PIN:

- decrypt.1234
- decrypt.4287
- decrypt.6862
- decrypt.8946

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try that